# How to retrieve all last posted tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get all tweets that are currently tweeted (Or all tweets that are tweeted the last hour). I want to filter and analyze them. But I could not find a way to do it. All explanations require an id to give or a hashtag to filter. But that is not what I am looking for.

I am using the StreamListener and I have read that the max_id and since_id would be helpful but they also require an id.

So my question would be: Is there a way to do this? Or an alternative way?

Comment: twitter charges a lot for "all tweets" these days, see their [decahose](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/overview/decahose) (which requires an enterprise subscription) and only gives you a random 10% of all tweets

Comment: Is there maybe a way around, e.g. to track multiple keywords like: "am","is","are",... to get as much tweets as possible?